# Service Fabric Instance's endpoint is not assigned IP address

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I created simple dummy service which I have deployed into my testing SF cluster, but when I check the deployed application/service in SF Explorer and its instances all of them does not have assigned Endpoint's URL. Instead, there is:

```
(none)      http://[::]:8322
```

I spent a half day trying to find a solution but I am not sure where is the problem.

The Service is Stateless service which uses ASP.NET Core 2.0 and Kestrel WebListener (it is basically slightly modified the template Service generated by Visual Studio when creating new ASP.NET Core Stateless service).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using version [2.7.198](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/08/09/release-of-sdk-2-7-198-and-runtime-5-7-198-for-windows/) (or greater for all you future readers) of the Service Fabric NuGet packages. This is the version that officially begins to support ASP.NET Core 2.0, which handles issues like this.